react native video does not load the video when textTracks is set for m3u8
I have been using this lib for android and ios, on ios according to docs you can not use textTracks for m3u8 videos!
but currently, android does not load the video too, when I try to add textTracks!
this was working before, it just stopped working!
here is the code :

 <Video
                  key={video}
                  ref={videoRef}
                  source={{
                    uri: video,
                    type: "m3u8",
                    metadata: {
                      title: activityName,
                      artist: "Learn",
                      imageUri: getFilePath(previewImage),
                    },
                  }}
                  preventsDisplaySleepDuringVideoPlayback={true}
                  repeat={false}
                  style={styles.backgroundVideo}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                  muted={false}
                  rate={currentSpeed}
                  paused={!play}
                  onProgress={onProgress}
                  onLoad={onLoadEnd}
                  onEnd={onEnd}
                  fullscreen={false}


                  selectedTextTrack={
                    subTitlesEnabled
                      ? {
                          type: SelectedTrackType.LANGUAGE,
                          value: "en",
                        }
                      : {
                          type: SelectedTrackType.DISABLED,
                        }
                  }
                  textTracks={[
                    {
                      title: "English Subtitles",
                      language: "en",
                      type: TextTrackType.VTT,
                      uri: "https://tkvj9u.cloudfront.net/courses/13476/videos/transcript_146414_58974319-a7dc-48f9-8da4-d389bae603ea.vtt",
                    },
                  ]}
                  playInBackground={true}
                  playWhenInactive={true}
                  showNotificationControls={true}
                  ignoreSilentSwitch="ignore"
                  subtitleStyle={{
                    fontSize: 14,
                    paddingBottom: 44,
                  }}
                />

I tried to change the value in text tracks and did it with another vtt file, still did not work!
